# TypeScript: Accessing outer "this" from literal getter

Tags: typescript, object-literal

When using getters and setters in object literals, I cannot see an easy way to access the outer "this" scope in Typescript. Consider the following:

```
class Report {
    stuff: any[];

    options = {
        length: 10,
        get maxLength() { return REPORT.stuff.length }
    }
}
```

Where `REPORT` wants to be a reference to the instance of the `Report` object. I realize that I can solve this by setting options within the constructor and using a `var REPORT = this` or similar, but seems inelegant. Is there a way to do this more cleanly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I realize that I can solve this by setting options within the constructor and using a var REPORT = this or similar, but seems inelegant

Instead of setting up option in the constructor you can take advantage of the fact that `options` *is being defined in the constructor. Thus, store `this` into `options`:

```
class Report {
    stuff: any[] = [];

    options = {
        _report: this,
        length: 10,
        get maxLength() { return (this._report as Report).stuff.length }
    }
}

let foo = new Report(); 
foo.stuff = [1,2];
console.log(foo.options.maxLength); // 2
```

Comment: After playing with it a bit, I came to this answer as well. It's still not perfect, in my opinion, but I'm guessing it's the best we can do for now.

Comment: The cast is needed. However `self = this` was left over from testing ... hence removed now, thanks 

Comment: @JohnnyHK without the cast it is `any` and unsafe

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the `this` binding of lambdas.

```
class Report {
    stuff: any[];

    options = {
        length: 10,
        maxLength: () => this.stuff.length
    }
}
```

compiles to

```
var Report = (function () {
    function Report() {
        var _this = this;
        this.options = {
            length: 10,
            maxLength: function () { return _this.stuff.length; }
        };
    }
    return Report;
})();
```

Edit:  This makes a function instead of a getter like you originally had.  I assumed that was a typo, until just now, when I just learned that's valid javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not result in the same object as in my example. I want maxLength to be a _value property_, where as in your example, it's a function. To access the value in my example, you write `report.options.maxLength` in yours, you would need `report.options.maxLength()`

Comment: @YonaAppletree:  Today, I learned that javascript has value properties.  I've not seen them before.  I know that fat-arrow lambdas can't be given names, so I don't see an elegant way of making such a getter.

Comment: I also just learned about getters / setters in object literals. I knew you could do it on an already-defined object with Object.defineProperty, but I did not know it was valid within a literal. I'm guessing this is where TypeScript got the syntax for it's property methods (or whatever they're actually called).